# CSS Image as Footer

Tags: html, css, image

I would like to use an image as a footer on my page.

Current HTML / CSS:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <img src="<?php echo base_url('/assets/artwork/image.png');?>" class="img-fluid">
    </div>
</div>
```

This works fine when the content is longer than the display window, however, when the page content isn't long enough, there is a gap between the image and the bottom of the page.

What do I need to add to ensure if the page contents isn't long enough for the display window, the footer image goes to the bottom of the display?

---

RESOLVED

Using method 3 - [css-tricks.com/couple-takes-sticky-footer](https://css-tricks.com/couple-takes-sticky-footer)

Updated HTML:

```
<body>
  <div class="content">
  content
  </div>
  <footer class="footer"></footer>
</body>
```

Updated CSS:

```
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.content {
  flex: 1 0 auto;
}
.footer {
  flex-shrink: 0;
}
```

Comment: Have a look here https://css-tricks.com/couple-takes-sticky-footer/

Comment: Thanks very much, Adam. I chose to use the flexbox method, and it worked!

Comment: You're very welcome. Glad you got it sorted.

Comment: Please edit your question and post your css.